# Get Enumerated type by Inc(type, Index) says "Left Side cannot be assigned to", why?

Tags: delphi

I'm more of a C/C++ person, but I'm converting a pascal module from having integer types in a wizard to enumerated types and have the following snag (it is to select a page directly via <kbd>Alt-0</kbd> to <kbd>Alt-9</kbd>):

```
procedure TfrmWizard.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  i, j: TWizPages;
begin
  j := Inc(Low(TWizPages), Key-Ord('0')); // << line with problem
```

The IDE complains on the comma that the `Left side cannot be assigned to`, and at the last parenthesis about `Incompatible types` (it doesn't give me much time to read it when I hover over it).

What is the correct way to do what I'm looking to do?

Comment: Inc is a procedure, not a function. The first parameter is the value being incremented, and you're attempting to pass a constant. See: https://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.php?Name=inc

Comment: Are you sure a variable of type `TWizPages` is a collection of pages, and not a single page? I suspect the plural suffix should be removed from the type name.

Answer (score 3):

`Inc` is a procedure, not a function such as `Succ`.  It increments the first value which can't be a constant.  Here's the working version:

```
procedure TfrmWizard.FormKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
var
  i, j: TWizPages;
begin
  j := Low(TWizPages);
  Inc(j, Key-Ord('0'));
```

Comment: What's the point of that when you could do `j:= Low( TWizPages )+ Key- Ord( '0' );` in one line right away? Why using `Inc()` at all when `+` would be enough?

Comment: @AmigoJack: Although you can certainly write that in your source code, I will not compile. You need `j := TWizPages(Ord(Low(TWizPages)) + Key - Ord('0'))`. You cannot add a `TWizPages` and an integer, assuming `TWizPages` is an enumerated type.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: I see. I just never used `Inc()` on enumerated types. Too bad the definition of `TWizPages` is nowhere given.

Comment: It's an `enumeration TWizPages = (whatever=0, however, everever);` and I found a page that said you can use `Inc` with enumerators so that's what I did, but looks like you can use + too.

Answer (score 2):

`Inc()` takes a reference to a variable, but you are passing it a constant.

Try this instead:

```pascal
j := TWizPages(Ord(Low(TWizPages)) + (Key-Ord('0')));
```